# How set default value in Dynamic Rows of dataProvider?

Tags: magento2

In XML form I have fields:
Name:
Phone:
Company:
Company - dynamic rows

```
 <fieldset name="dynamic_rows_set">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Dynamic Rows</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <container name="dynamic_rows_container">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/dynamic-rows</item>
                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/dynamic-rows/templates/default</item>
                    <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">dynamicRows</item>
                    <item name="recordTemplate" xsi:type="string">company</item>
                    <item name="addButtonLabel" xsi:type="string">Add slider</item>
                    <item name="deleteProperty" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <container name="company">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Sliders</item>
                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/record</item>
                        <item name="isTemplate" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="is_collection" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="showFallbackReset" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
                <field name="company_name">
                    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Slider name</item>
                            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">slider_name</item>
                            <item name="showFallbackReset" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                            <item name="default" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                            </item>
                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">10</item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </field>

                <actionDelete>
                    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">actionDelete</item>
                            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                            <item name="fit" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Actions</item>
                            <item name="additionalClasses" xsi:type="string">data-grid-actions-cell</item>
                            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Backend/dynamic-rows/cells/action-delete</item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </actionDelete>
            </container>
        </container>
    </fieldset>
```

How I can do in dataprovider :

```
If(!$this->loadedData) 
{
   return default 10~ companies which I get in DB
}
```

ty!

Comment: share your data provider code.

Comment: @ChiragPatel https://codeshare.io/5RoDOj

Comment: Hi, did you solve this? The answer only works for editing existing records

Answer (score 2):

Use code below in DataProvider file:

```
if (null === $this->loadedData) {
    $this->loadedData[''] = [
        'database_field_name' => [
            [
                'field1' => 'field_value',
                'field2'  => 'field_value',
            ],
            [
                'field1' => 'field_value',
                'field2'  => 'field_value',
            ]
        ]
    ];
}
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use code below in DataProvider file:

```
if (null === $this->loadedData) {
    $this->loadedData[''] = [
        'database_field_name' => [
            [
                'field1' => 'field_value',
                'field2'  => 'field_value',
            ],
            [
                'field1' => 'field_value',
                'field2'  => 'field_value',
            ]
        ]
    ];
}
```

It will worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code in dataProvider file

```
$this->loadedData['id of your db row']['dynamic_rows_set']['company_name'] = 'company name value';
```

Note: must change **id of your db row** with your mysql table row

Comment: row table, or ? (I create new record, not edit)

Comment: id of your edit record